# jdbcTemplate ManyToOne

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

jdbcTemplate return a transaction object with empty column or null

```
@Entity
public class Transaction implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String accountnNumber;
    private String checkNumber;
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "banque_id")
    private Bank bank;
    ...
}

public List<Transaction> getFiltre(FiltreTransaction filtre) {

    //DAO
    String sql = "select * from Transaction where id = 74";
    RowMapper<Transaction> rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Transaction>(Transaction.class);
   return this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper); 
}
```

Answer:

```
{
    "id": 73,
    "accountnNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "checkNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "banque": null,
}
```

why bank is null while in the database it is not null ?? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed JPA and Spring's `JDBCTemplate` and `BeanPropertyRowMapper`. As per [Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html), in the `BeanPropertyRowMapper`:

> Column values are mapped based on matching the **column name** as obtained from result set metadata to **public setters** for the corresponding properties. The names are matched either directly or by transforming a name separating the parts with underscores to the same name using "camel" case.

So the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` disregards JPA annotations and expects a column (`BANQUE_ID` most probably) from the result set to match to a corresponding `Long banqueId` property of the `Transaction` bean. Conversely, to set the `bank` property of the bean, it would expect a `BANK` column in the result set, **as long as it is of a simple type:**

> Mapping is provided for fields in the target class for many common types, e.g.: String, boolean, Boolean, byte, Byte, short, Short, int, Integer, long, Long, float, Float, double, Double, BigDecimal, java.util.Date, etc.

I do not think the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` can map to a related entity, when used as in the code from the question.

This is why the `bank` (or `banque`) property is null, the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` does not even try to set it because there is no corresponding column in the result set and it is not supposed to know how to set related entities anyway.

**I'd suggest you cleared the design of whatever you are doing and decide, are you using JPA, Spring's JDBCTemplate, a mix?**

Comment: Nikos Paraskevopoulos thanks for your answer, you're quite right,
 I mixed in between, normally I work with JPA, now I'm working on a filter part so I need to build a query in the code, 
I have look for and I do not think JPA is doing this kind of work '@query'